# Adding and removing an item to a list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code for adding and removing an item to a list(not sure about the removing part) but it doesn't work. My IDE doesn't give me any errors. I also need to add a frame around the app but I'm not sure how to do that either. Any pointers on what needs to be fixed?

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {

  var text = document.getElementById("lista").value;
  var li = "<li> + text + </li>";

  document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(li);
}

function myFunction() {
  var list = document.getElementById("lista");
  list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
}

console.log(text);
```

```html
<form name="SimpleToDo">
  <table>

    <h1>SimpleToDo</h1>

    <p style="text-align: left;">ToDo:</p>
    <input type="text" id="lista" />
    <input type='button' value='Lisaa' id='add' />
    <input type='button' value='Tyhjaa lista' id='delete' />
  </table>

  <ul id='lista'></ul>

</form>
```

Comment: `"<li> + text + </li>"` – this is not how concatenation works in JS. This is one single text literal, that contains the _text_ `<li> + text + </li>`

Comment: "document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(li);"
You have two distinct elements with the id 'lista'

Comment: `console.log(text);` – `text` does not exist in that context, it is a local variable in the scope of the click handler callback function.

Comment: @CBroe How does it work then, I found the snippet here on Stack.

Comment: My bad, I did not see that you were using the same ID twice. But then that is already not allowed in HTML to begin with. All in all, this really sounds like you should maybe go and find yourself a couple of beginner tutorials, and work through those first …

Comment: @RussJ do I create another id then?

Answer (score 0):

To append "li", you must create an element like `var li = document.createElement('li');`

Then you append "text" in "li" like `li.appendChild(text);`

And then you can append "li" in "lista" `document.getElementById('lista').appendChild(li);`

I hope that my answer will be clear to you and that it will have helped you